# What am I doing wrong with this Python class? AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'usernames'

Tags: class, python-2.7, object

Hey there I am trying to make my first class my code is as follows:

```
class Twitt:
def __init__(self):
    self.usernames = []
    self.names = []
    self.tweet = []
    self.imageurl = []

def twitter_lookup(self, coordinents, radius):
    twitter = Twitter(auth=auth)
    coordinents = coordinents + "," + radius
    print coordinents
    query = twitter.search.tweets(q="", geocode='33.520661,-86.80249,50mi', rpp=10)
    print query
    for result in query["statuses"]:
        self.usernames.append(result["user"]["screen_name"])
        self.names.append(result['user']["name"])
        self.tweet.append(h.unescape(result["text"]))
        self.imageurl.append(result['user']["profile_image_url_https"])
```

What I am trying to be able to do is then use my class like so:

```
test = Twitt()
hello = test.twitter_lookup("38.5815720,-121.4944000","1m")
print hello.usernames
```

This does not work and I keep getting: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'usernames'"

Maybe I just misunderstood the tutorial or am trying to use this wrong. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the error is `test.twitter_lookup("38.5815720,-121.4944000","1m")` return nothing. If you want the usernames, you need to do

```
test = Twitt()
test.twitter_lookup("38.5815720,-121.4944000","1m")
test.usernames
```

Comment: @ZachJohnson you welcome, if you can, select as correct answer :) it would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `twitter_lookup` is modifying the `Twitt` object in-place. You didn't make it return any kind of value, so when you call `hello = test.twitter_lookup()`, there's no return value to assign to `hello`, and it ends up as `None`. Try `test.usernames` instead.

Alternatively, have the `twitter_lookup` function put its results in some new object (perhaps a dictionary?) and `return` it. This is probably the more sensible solution.

Also, the function accepts a `coordinents` (it's 'coordinates') argument, but then throws it away and uses a hard-coded value instead.

Comment: Ah thank you very much I get it now. And yeah I was preparing the "coordinents" (lol at my poor spelling) argument and had an issue with formatting so I hard coded in a set of coordinates I knew would work.